# How to reduce mongoose query for connectionFromPromisedArray in Relay?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, mongoose, relayjs

Let's say we have mongoose model of droids and we need to resolve a collection in queryType with method like below:

```
resolve: (source, args) => connectionFromPromisedArray(Droid.find(), args),
```

As far as I understand we will fetch more data than we need from MongoDB.

I've tried to write a function that will handle fetching exactly what I need, but then I lose my pageInfo, because Relay assume that my data haven't pages.

So far I've found some libs with one function but every time it bloats app.

Also it would be great to use cursors with mongoose.

Here is example of handling it from [graffiti by rising-stack](https://github.com/RisingStack/graffiti-mongoose/blob/master/src/query/query.js#L266-L321), but I'm not sure that it will be works properly with new versions of Relay at client side.

Comment: The connection specification of Relay didn't change, so the example you provided will for sure still work. What are you looking for ? An example implementation of the relay connection with Mongoose ?

Comment: Example works thats right, but the main issue here is overfetching. Yes, I wish too much to have a clarity about necessity of changing connectionFromPromisedArray to some mongoose funciton.

Comment: I meant the example of graffiti by rising-stack

Comment: This one isn't opverfetching

Comment: Yes, but I need to contain this logic in separate function and not sure that it would be convenient and not error prone with Relay. So the purpose of my answer is related to connectionFromPromisedArray - I will be glad if it handle overfetching somehow or I need to change it to another function to avoid it?